# AppDelegate.Swift compile error after updating to Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, appdelegate

I recently updated a project after not touching it for a year or two, and now I'm having some issues.

Everything worked before and I even went thru each error to update the new syntax, but I'm stuck at one function in AppDelegate.Swift that's preventing me from running the program. It's this one here:

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = Bundle.mainBundle.url(forResource: "ProjectName", withExtension: "momd")
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL ?? <#default value#>)!
}()
```

After I take the suggestions from Xcode and update the Syntax it looks like this:

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ProjectName", withExtension: "momd")
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL ?? <#default value#>)!
}()
```

I'm really confused as to what to put for the **default value** as I've never edited or touched AppDelegate before.
What do I need to put here?

Thank you for any help you may provide!

Comment: Rather than worrying about “default value”, just unwrap `modelURL` optional (e.g. `guard let modelURL = ... else { fatalError("database not found") }` or just `let modelURL = Bundle.mainBundle.url(forResource: "ProjectName", withExtension: "momd")!`. Then you don't need that `nil` coalescing operator at all.

Comment: That is not a problem with updating to Swift 5. The first code block does not compile in an earlier Swift version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the application doesn't work at all if the model is missing you can force unwrap the URL

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ProjectName", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()
```

Consider that since iOS 10, macOS 10.12 there is a [more convenient way to initialize the Core Data stack with `NSPersistentContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/setting_up_a_core_data_stack)